# How to show dropdown of AutoCompleteTextView after some seconds of last typed letter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, autocompletetextview

Well, I have to call api to get data from server and show in AutoCompleteTextView. I can fetch that search results perfectly but the problem is that when, I type single letter in to the AutoCompleteTextView then each and every time api executes which is not good user experience and it takes too much time.

Although, I have created some logic to get data after some seconds but it only works when I type next letter.

```
        String sec;
        
        home_name_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Format sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
            if (s.length() >= 3) { // minimum 3 letters to execute api.
                if (s.length() == 3) {
                    sec = sdf.format(new Date());
                } else {
                    try {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
                        String Cdate = sdf.format(new Date());
                        Date d1 = sdf2.parse(sec);
                        Date d2 = sdf2.parse(Cdate);
                        long CompareDate = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                        if (CompareDate >= 3000) {
                            //here my api executes in AsyncTask.
                            sec = sdf.format(new Date());
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timer to wait:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final long DELAY = 1000; // You can give the time(1000 =1 sec.)
home_name_search.addTextChangedListener(
new TextWatcher() {
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // You can call API.
                }
            },
            DELAY
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was so easy but I made it complicated...it's work